# hiding the navigation bar while scrolling SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Hello I am new to swiftUI and am making my first app, my current issue is that I am not sure if it is possible to hide my navigation bar while scrolling using the methods I got from a nav bar tutorial I found. I have tried to implement the UINavigationBar stuff but I don't think its at all compatable with what I have so far. I'm pretty sure if I wanted to go that route I would have to rewrite most of what I have to fit that format.

I was hoping that maybe I am missing a step when doing this so I don't have to rewrite what I have

here's my current code

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View{
    @State var showMenu = false
    @State var scoreUp = false
    @State var commentP = false
    @State var tags = false
    @State var sauce = false
    
    
    var body: some View{
        let drag = DragGesture()
            .onEnded {
                if $0.translation.width < -100 {
                withAnimation {
                self.showMenu = false
                                    }
                            }
        }
        let dragOpen = DragGesture()
            .onEnded {
                if $0.translation.width > 100 {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showMenu = true
                    }
                }
            }
        return NavigationView {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
               /// this is the main view for the second page allowing most of the app features
                MainView(showMenu: self.$showMenu, scoreUp: self.$scoreUp, commentP : self.$commentP,tags : self.$tags,sauce :self.$sauce)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .offset(x: self.showMenu ? geometry.size.width/2 : 0)
                .disabled(self.showMenu ? true : false)
                .gesture(dragOpen)
                if self.showMenu {
                    HamburgerMenuView(showMenu: self.$showMenu)
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/2, height: geometry.size.height)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                        .gesture(drag)
                        
            
                }
                if self.scoreUp {
                    // TO DO : MAke this button score up a post
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.up")
                        .animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 50, damping: 1), value: 10)
                    }
                }
            }
        .navigationBarItems(leading: (
            Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
            self.showMenu.toggle()
        
                                    }
                }) {
            Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                .imageScale(.large)
            }
        ))
        }
    }
}

// this is the main view for both the content view and when the menu is displayed
struct MainView: View{
    
    ///  shows the hamburger menu when set to true
    @Binding var showMenu : Bool
    
    /// SCORES up posts when set to true
    
    @Binding var scoreUp : Bool
    
    
    ///  allows  the user to add a comment to the post if set to true
    ///  move the view up and give the user a text box
    @Binding var commentP : Bool
    
    
    ///  allows the user to see the Tags on the image
    
    @Binding var tags : Bool
    ///  allows the user to see the Source on the image
    
    
    @Binding var sauce : Bool
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack() {
            
            Image("");
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading){
                Text("Test")

                .bold();
                    
                Image("Test")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
               
                HStack() {
                    
                Button(action : {
                    withAnimation{
                    self.scoreUp = true
                }
                       print("Score up")
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.up")
                            .padding(1)
                        
                    
                    };
                    Text("1025");
                
                    Button(action : {
                    withAnimation{
                    self.commentP = true
                }
                       print("comment")
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "text.bubble")
                            .padding(1)
                        
                    
                    };
                Button(action : {
                    withAnimation{
                    self.tags = true
                }
                       print("Tags")
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "tag")
                            .padding(1)
                    };
                Button(action : {
                    withAnimation{
                    self.sauce = true
                    }
                    print("sauce?")
                    }) {
                    Image(systemName: "eyes")
                        .padding(1)
                    
                };
            }
                Text("Test")
                Image("Test")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit();
                
                Text("Test")
                Image("Test")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                
            }
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                self.showMenu = true
            }
            print("Open the side menu")
        }) {
            Text("Show Menu");
            }
        .hidden()
        }
            }
                }
            
            }
       
        }
        
        }
 

/// this is the hamburger menu itself
struct HamburgerMenuView : View {
    @Binding var showMenu : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Profile")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding(10)
                }
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Settings")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(10)
                }
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Favorites")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(10)
                }
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Posts")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(10)
                }
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Comments")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(10)
                }
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Artists")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(10)
                }
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Tags")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(10)
                }
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("More")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(10)
                }
            
            }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .background(Color(red: 32/255, green: 32/255, blue: 32/255))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
            }
        
        Spacer()
        }
    }

//// TO DO
//class underImageBar {
//
//
//HStack() {
//Button(action : {
//    withAnimation{
//    self.scoreUp = true
//}
//       print("Score up")
//    }) {
//        Image(systemName: "arrow.up")
//            .padding()
//
//
//    };
//Button(action : {
//    withAnimation{
//    self.commentP = true
//}
//       print("comment")
//    }) {
//        Image(systemName: "text.bubble")
//            .padding()
//
//
//    };
//Button(action : {
//    withAnimation{
//    self.tags = true
//}
//       print("Tags")
//    }) {
//        Image(systemName: "tag")
//            .padding()
//    };
//Button(action : {
//    withAnimation{
//    self.sauce = true
//    }
//    print("sauce?")
//    }) {
//    Image(systemName: "eyes")
//        .padding()
//
//        };
//    }
//}

/// this previews the code
struct menuView: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
                .toolbar {
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[this was supposed to be a gif stack overflow just made it a jpeg lol?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwHQS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is a view modifier for that.

```
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

I hope this helps out.

Comment: hey thanks for the advice, but unfortunately I'm not sure I can add a modifier to this to only hide it while scrolling. I appreciate the response tho!